# Zend Framework how to map DbTable model to database table and insert new row

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I cannot figure out how to correctly map a DbTable model to a database row in a table in my DB and correspondingly extend this DbTable model to another model so that I can insert a new row. Any simple examples and explanation would be very helpful, as I am struggling in the logic of this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'model' here?

Comment: Check out my answer below. My DbTable tells each model which table I am using once I extend it to my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. For example, in my Application_Model_DbTable_ExTable add

```
protected $_name = 'ExTable';
```

This way Zend will know which table in the database to use.

I then extended Application_Model_DbTable_ExTable to my Application_Model_ExTable, and once I did that I was able to insert into my database using an array such as

```
public function ExFunction ($example){
    $data = array(                
        'example_column_name' => $example,
    );
    $this->insert($data);            
}
```